# Product data (Images, nutritional, ingredients, descriptions etc.) for vitamins & supplements

Tags: data-request

Where can I find product data (images, nutritional data, ingredients, descriptions etc.) for vitamins & supplements? I have the UPCs.

In the electronics and consumer products there are few providers, cannot find for the vitamins & supplements.

This is needed for a commerce site.

If there is no provider, is there another way that is recommended to semi automate the information gathering.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have UPC's - have you thought about scraping Amazon or Google Products?

Comment: ...not 100% on this, but sounds like your answer is more ideally fitted for being a comment...at least until you hear back/know its the correct answer

Comment: Thank you, yes can you please direct me to a user friendly solution, saw a lot of API queries etc.. but could not find a tool that can implement it for more that 1 query